# Android Screenshot views rotation does not appear

Tags: android, rotation, snapshot

I'm trying to get screenshot of whole screen with the codes below. The problem is that if any view has rotation screenshot gives me the first state of the view without rotation so the rotation does not appear. How can I get the screen shot with last states of view?

I have similar problem with arch or rounded corners that will applied after the layout created.

```
val v1 = window.decorView.rootView
            v1.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache(true))
            v1.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false



fun loadBitmapFromView(context: Context, v: View): Bitmap {
    val dm = context.resources.displayMetrics
    v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.widthPixels, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.heightPixels, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight())
    val returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
            v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val c = Canvas(returnedBitmap)
    v.draw(c)

    return returnedBitmap
}
```

Comment: have you tried this without calling measure and layout on the view youre trying to capture?

Comment: tried it but same result